# Align figures in the centre of the cells using tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, includegraphics

I created the following table:

[image]

I can't figure out how to align the figures in the centre of their cells, without enlarging the length of the table. The figures need to fit in this size of the cell. I don't want to overlap the pagenumber below.
I've been dealing with this problem for a while now and haven't been able to come up with a solution that answers my criteria.
I'm open to any suggestions and your expertise. I am relatively new in Latex, so forgive me if the answer is obvious. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfigure}         %all the packages of the whole document
\usepackage{stanli}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{array} 
    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Operations}
    \label{table_Operations}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.70\linewidth}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{Icon} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Description}} \\ \hline
        1         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Compound_Operation.png}        & Compound Operation                 & This operation creates a compound operation which is a sequence of operations. These operations may be of different types such as object flow, device, compound, etc.\\ \hline
        2         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_NonSim_Operation.png}       & Non-Sim Operation                  & This operation creates a non-simulated operation which is an operation used for marking time intervals or for marking the place of an operation that will be created later.\\ \hline
        3         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Object_Flow_Operation.png}       & Object Flow Operation              & This operation creates an object flow operation to move an object along a path.\\ \hline
        4         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Device_Operation.png}      & Device Operation                   & This operation moves a device from one pose to another. \\ \hline
        5         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Grip_Operation.png}      & Gripper Operation                  & This operation is meant for a gripping device, which can grip and release.\\ \hline
        6         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Device_Control_Group_Operation.png}       &  Device Control Group Operation   & This operation creates a device-control-group that moves a group of devices from one pose to another. The group of devices is defined and then the pose is defined using 'Edit Pose Groups'.\\ \hline
        7         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Weld_Operation.png} & Weld Operation                     & This operation is meant for a weld robot with a mounted gun or workpiece. The weld operation is comprised of weld location operations.\\ \hline
        8         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Continuous_Feature_Operation.png}       &  Continuous Feature Operation   & This operation creates a continuous feature operation which is meant for a robot performing laser welding or glue applications. A Continuous Feature operation is comprised of continuous manufacturing operations.\\ \hline
        9         & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_PickPlace_Operation.png}       & Pick and Place   Operation         & This creates a pick-and-place for moving an object form one place to another.\\ \hline
        10        & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Generic_Robot_Operation.png}        & Generic Robotic   Operation        & This creates a robotic operation for general use.\\ \hline
        11        & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Robot_Path_Generator.png}       &  Robot Path Reference Operation  & This operations creates a Robot Path Reference (RPR) that runs in Line Simulation Mode. An RPR operation activates robotic operations within a robotic program.\\ \hline
        12        & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{NewEdit_Concurrent_Robotic_Operation.png}       &  Concurrent Robotic Operation  & This operation creates a concurrent robotic operation for moving a dual-arm robot or multiple robots. Multiple operations are grouped and preform synchronized, cooperative or load sharing mode.\\ \hline
        13        & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{New_Robotic_Program.png}       & Robotic Program                    & This operation creates a robotic program for a robot. A program is defined as a collection of operations.\\ \hline
        14        & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{Human_Compound_Operation.png}       &  Human Compound  Operation & Creates a human compound operation. This operation is similar to the regular compound operation.\\ \hline
        15        & \includegraphics[scale=.75]{Create_Posture_Operation.png}       & Create Posture   Operation         & This creates a posture operation for a moving human to a specific posture.\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't show code as an image it makes it very hard to debug, provide a small but complete test document. Your output looks rather unexpected as the images in column 2 appear to be over-printing the `\hline` above which should not happen unless you have inserted negative space somewhere.

Comment: that said `\raisebox{-10pt}{\includegraphics...`  probably does what you want.

Comment: Right, my bad! I should have known better. I'm sorry, I'll edit the question.
The output indeed looks unexpected. Only if I extremely zoom in the hline is partially visible. 
The raisebox indeed has a desirable effect! Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for MWE (Minimal Working Example) +1 for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following MWE (unfortunately you not provide any information about your document nor code for your table, so in it is used dummy text).

In MWE is by use of `adjustbox` package images baselines moved to the top of images, images size are set by `\adjustboxset` and for inclusion in table  is used `\adjincludegraphics` instruction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype} % for better spacing of text
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\adjustboxset{width=12mm,valign=t,   % <--- asumed that all images have equal size
              margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt}% <---
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = { Q[c] Q[c] X[j] X[3,j] },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c}
            }
    &   Icon
        &   Name
            &   Description     \\
1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} 
        & Compound operation  
            &   \lipsum[1][1]   \\
2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
        & Non-Sim Operation
            &   \lipsum[1][1-2] \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the lack of information. I have edited the question. 
Thanks for sharing this method!

Comment: Does suggested solution fulfill your expectation? If do this on the best way, you can consider to accept answer (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer)  or at least when you have enough reputation, up-vote it.

Comment: Yes the solution is good. My reputation is indeed not sufficient enough I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put inside yours pictures):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx} % For example picture
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|0c|0c|0c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\ \hline
            a & \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth, valign=c]{logoRS.png} & momento relativistico \\ \hline
            c & \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth, valign=c]{Cecilia.png} & d \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: This works, thank you! Figures are nicely aligned and the table still fits the page. The only remark I have is that valign=c in my document is highlighted in red with the caption 'unrecognized key in key option'. Do you maybe know what I've done wrong?

Comment: Sorry I can't control your preamble. Perhaps some incompatibility.

Comment: Of course, I understand. I don't see the mistake either, perhaps you are right.